# Problem with calling program from the command line

Tags: utilities, executable, path

Note: this is a cross post with [this post](http://j.mp/niohtD) on SO.

I am trying to build a command line wrapper in Python 3 for an exiting command line tool called 'spooky' and I am having a hard time understanding some strange behavior. If I type `spooky` on the command line, it brings up the man page for spooky. If I enter the path to the spooky tool (`/path/to/spooky`) on the command line it also brings up the man page for spooky.

I can run the spooky program successfully if I place spooky in my path and then enter the required arguments like this:

```
`$ spooky -a 50 -b .97`
```

However, if I do not put spooky in my path and type the following the command it will not run.

```
`$ /path/to/spooky -a 50 -b .97`
```

Why won't this program run when I enter the program's path and then the required arguments? Thanks for the help!